# Google Developer Console android crashes and ANR

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a published android app.

On the first page I go to on developer console it has some stats.

One of the is "crashes and ANRs".

Are these automatically reported by android/play services out of the box?

Or do I need to opt in to them somehow?

mine reports '-' character under this stat. Does that mean zero, or like no data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to opt in.

However, to my knowledge, these are only crashes when the user has pressed the submit crash report error when the app crashed.

`-` means zero or no crashes for that matter

Answer (score 0):

As Google states (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=en-GB):

"You'll see all ANRs collected from Android devices whose users have opted in to automatically share usage and diagnostics data. Data is available for the previous two months. For more information about how Android users opt in to share data, go to the [Accounts Help Centre](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6078260)."

In the Accounts Help Centre's article, Google explains how users can enable and disable sharing the information and what information is shared.

Comment: That article is titled "Share usage & diagnostics information with Google". It does not sound like it is sharing logs with app developers. Perhaps it is though. Super unclear, but I guess that is not unusual.

Comment: @mikenelson I agree the title of the document isn't very clear. The usage and diagnostics are recorded via the Android log(s) on the end-user's device AFAIK and  then transmitted to Google via Google Play Services running on the device. I've yet to track down all the necessary code to know exactly how the system works. I'd love to know more  from anyone who has insights.